# Installing .air Application Silently

Tags: air, adobe, silent-installer

I am trying to install Adobe AIR along with a .air file as one package in ManageEngine Desktop Central 10 silently. I have gotten as far as silently installing Adobe Air using the command/switch: AdobeAIRInstaller.exe -silent.

Then, I created a post-deployment script (filename.air -eulaAccepted -silent) in ManageEngine. Adobe AIR installs silently and flawlessly, but the .air file simply opens up with the installation prompt. I have also tried various silent install switches tailed to the .air file within the command prompt, but to no avail.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\Adobe AIR\Versions\1.0\Adobe AIR Application Installer.exe" -silent -eulaAccepted "filepath\filename.air"
```

Good Luck!